# Azure Pipeline cannot build File scoped project

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have built a solution that builds well on local and runs well on direct deploy. When I want to deploy via Pipeline I get errors like this:

> Classname.cs(4,35): Error CS1514: { expected

If the structure is

```
namespace PostgreDataAccess.Models
{
  public class ClassName
  {
      public string prop1 { get; set; }

      public string prop2  { get; set; }
  }
}
```

it has no problem, but If I try

```
namespace PostgreDataAccess.Models;
public class ClassName
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    public string prop2  { get; set; }
}
```

I have series of the quoted error.

I have so many classes like this, how can I solve this problem at once without having to edit over 103 class?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your pipeline is using an older version of the compiler that doesn't understand the newer syntax.

Comment: it is using .net core 6, should be able to sun it

Comment: I would need to see the pipeline to understand why it isn't working.

Comment: It is a private system, cannot show it

Comment: Then nobody here can help you. We only need to see the relevant parts of the pipeline definition.

Comment: I do not have access to this system

Comment: all i can actually do  is a merge and see the error

Comment: Then perhaps you need to speak to the person who builds the pipelines in your company.

Comment: "Classname.cs(4,35): Error CS1514: { expected"

This is very likely due to the new "permissions" on updated versions of C#. Is it in C# 8.0? Where namespace no longer needs the "{}"? I can't remember... 

But likely you built your code on the pipeline with a compiler, that works on C# 6.0 but you are locally using the newest version of C# 8.0. 

Either revert you namespace definitions back to pre- 8.0 OR update the pipeline compiler, like @DavidG recommended.

8.0 can still understand the syntax of 6.0 but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a buch @DavidG, I appreciate. It is indeed the version error. It needs newer version of C#. I have painfully reverted to the Blocked scope version of codding. took a while.

Answer (score 1):

"Classname.cs(4,35): Error CS1514: { expected" This is very likely due to the new "permissions" on updated versions of C#. Is it in C# 8.0? Where namespace no longer needs the "{}"? I can't remember... But likely you built your code on the pipeline with a compiler, that works on C# 6.0 but you are locally using the newest version of C# 8.0. Either revert you namespace definitions back to pre- 8.0 OR update the pipeline compiler, like @DavidG recommended. 8.0 can still understand the syntax of 6.0 but not vice versa.